# How to express Math.cos or Math.acos for Android?

Tags: java

I have tried writing this in Android and I get NAN as the result. This is my current code can someone verify this, and if it is not correct, offer me the correct equation.

```
 Math.acos((((a*a)+(c*c))-(b*b))/(2*b*c));
```

[image]

Comment: b and c are not ints are they? If so, you're doing int division and will need to cast one of them to double in the division.

Comment: acos((a*a+c*c-b*b)/2.0*b*c)

Comment: What parameters are you passing in to get a NaN that should not be NaN?

Comment: @ShivamKalra that worked as well. In all honesty it was the variables being sent that were messing it up. I had double checked a few times and all looked good before I got to this cos issue. SO I was just puzzled. Lot of if statements leading up to this equation, I had to go back and do the old trial and error and see where I went wrong. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.acos((a*a+c*c-b*b)/(2.0*b*c))
```

2.0 is used to convert it into double, you could also use
    Math.acos((a*a+c*c-b*b)/(2d*b*c)) instead where d in 2d means treat int 2 as double type

Comment: Huh? You're multiplying instead of dividing by `bc`. Math.acos((a*a+c*c-b*b)/(2.0*b*c)) as in the original question maybe?